# Bell's Original Paper - Local hidden variable theories correlations smaller than entanglement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, bells-inequality

I'm having trouble following Bell's derivation of equation 22 in [his original paper](https://cds.cern.ch/record/111654/files/vol1p195-200_001.pdf). Particularly, how to go from

$$
| \overline{P} (\vec{a}, \vec{b}) - \overline{P}(\vec{a}, \vec{c}) | \leq 1 + \overline{P}(\vec{b}, \vec{c}) + \varepsilon + \delta
$$

to

$$
| \vec{a} \cdot \vec{c} - \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} | - 2 (\varepsilon + \delta) \leq 1 - \vec{b} \cdot \vec{c} + 2(\varepsilon + \delta)
$$

using

\begin{equation}
| \overline{P}(\vec{a}, \vec{b}) + \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} | \leq \varepsilon + \delta. \qquad(1)
\end{equation}

My attempt was

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\overline{P}(\vec{b}, \vec{c}) + \vec{b} \cdot \vec{c} \leq | \overline{P}(\vec{b}, \vec{c}) + \vec{b} \cdot \vec{c} | \leq \varepsilon + \delta\\
\implies & \overline{P}(\vec{b}, \vec{c}) \leq (\varepsilon + \delta) - \vec{b} \cdot \vec{c}\\
\implies & 1 + (\varepsilon + \delta) + \overline{P}(\vec{b}, \vec{c}) \leq 1 - \vec{b} \cdot \vec{c} + 2(\varepsilon + \delta)\\
\implies& | \overline{P} (\vec{a}, \vec{b}) - \overline{P}(\vec{a}, \vec{c})| \leq 1 - \vec{b} \cdot \vec{c} + 2(\varepsilon + \delta)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

How do I deal with the left hand side, i.e., the absolute value of difference of probabilities using $(1)$?

**Edited to add more info**

We are dealing with a pair of spin one-half particles in a singlet state moving freely in opposite directions.

$$
P (\vec{a}, \vec{b}) \equiv \int d \lambda \rho(\lambda)A(\vec{a}, \lambda) B(\vec{b}, \lambda)
$$

where $\lambda$ is a continuous parameter, $\rho(\lambda)$ is its probability distributions and $A(\vec{a}, \lambda) = \pm 1$, $B(\vec{a}, \lambda) \pm 1$ are the possibles results of measuring spin components $\vec{\sigma}_{1}, \vec{\sigma}_{2}$ along $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$ respectively.

The probabilities $\overline{P}$s are nonnegative, the vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$ are unit vectors and I'm assuning $\varepsilon, \delta > 0$.

Comment: You will need to add details. What is P, how is it defined? You can't expect people to go and read the paper for you.

Comment: But, looking at it, isn't it just some triangle inequalities?

Comment: I wasn't expecting people to go and read the paper, I was hoping that someone who read the paper could help. Will add more information, but I guess it's not the right place for this kind of specific questions about a specific paper.

Comment: I remember having and answering this question when I read this paper, but I no longer have my notes from 2005. I'll try and write an answer later.

Comment: @rob As far as I can tell you just insert (1) into the first line and get the second (in fact, with one factor of 2 only being 1). As far as I can tell this is homework-type.

Comment: @RichardCosta As by my second comment, as far as I can see you can just always replace P(x,y) by $x \cdot y$, with an error of $\epsilon+\delta$. If you do this both on the lhs and rhs, you should get said inequality. (On the lhs, the error makes the value smaller, on the right hand side, bigger.)

Comment: ... $-\vec x\cdot \vec y$, of course.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Not a homework, just curious and got stuck.

Comment: "Homework-*type*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Equation (1) says is that if you replace $P(\vec x,\vec y)$ by $-\vec x\cdot \vec y$, you incur an error of at most $\pm (\epsilon+\delta)$.

Now do this both on the rhs and the lhs of your first equation:

1. On the lhs of the "$\le$", in the worst case the error will make the value larger, which means you need to put a minus sign to still satisfy the inequality. You do two replacements, thus $-2(\epsilon+\delta)$.
2. On the rhs, in the worst case the error will make the value smaller. Thus, you get an extra $+(\epsilon+\delta)$.

If you want to formalize this, this can be done by the triangle inequality, plus the following variant thereof: If $|a-b|\le \eta$, then $b-\eta \le a \le b+\eta$.